# angular.copy() does not break reference to model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Let's say I have a `model.data` object and want to copy that object to `datacopy` and do some changes on that new object (`datacopy`). But when I change `datacopy`, changes are also applied to `model.data`. How to stop that?

```
function updateClone (_object) {
    var datacopy = angular.copy(model.data);
    var index = _.findIndex(datacopy, function (obj) {
                            return obj.id === _object.id;
                        });

    datacopy.splice(index, 1, _object);
    }
```

Comment: Could you share the contents of `model`?

Answer (score 1):

Because of reputation I can't comment to question.

**Angular.copy()** works fine.

You can try this variant : **copy object outside of function and send it as parameter**.

```
function updateClone (datacopy, _object) 
{
    var index = _.findIndex(datacopy, function (obj) {
                                return obj.id === _object.id;
                            });

    datacopy.splice(index, 1, _object);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am sure that `angular.copy` is working fine.

What I believe is going on is that the model is storing a references to some other objects. When you `angular.copy(model.data)` the data is copied with the nested references: http://jsfiddle.net/pxcf2dqw/2/

```
var toy = {
    price: 50
}

var model = {
    data: toy
}

var datacopy = angular.copy(model.data);
datacopy.price = 50

console.log(datacopy.price)
console.log(model.data.price)
```